# javascript scope with object method

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I'm trying to bind divs with an object such that the divs have methods that can be acted upon. In particular I want when a user to clicks on a a div, for it to start moving across the screen, then if you click another div, it too starts moving.

For some reason my this.element inside the moveCarForward method function is undefined.

```js
function Car(element) {
  this.element = element;
  this.element.addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.style.border = "3px solid hotpink";
    startDrive();
  }, false);

  startDrive = function() {
    this.carDrivingInterval = setInterval(moveCarForward, 3000);
  }

  moveCarForward = function() {
    this.element.style.x = this.element.offsetLeft + 10 + "px";
  }
}

var arrayCarsElements = document.getElementsByClassName("car");
var arrCar = [];

for (var i = 0; i < arrayCarsElements.length; i++) {
  arrCar[i] = new Car(arrayCarsElements[i]);
}
```

```html
<div class="car" id="tesla" style="width: 50px; height: 50px; background: #ccc; margin-bottom: 10px;"></div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Comment: `moveCarForward` is a global variable, not a method. Consider using `"use strict";`.

Comment: this inside the moveCarForward method will be the window. that's why it's undefined.use ES6 arrow functions

Comment: to continue from @melpomene's comment, you can make moveCarForward into a method by defining it as `this.moveCarForward`

Answer (score 1):

[How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work) explains how `this` works. I recommend checking it out.

Interacting with your `Object` while retaining its reference would necessary in this scenario. Defining `this` (`new Object()`) and referencing back to the `Object` within your functions will do the trick.

```js
var Car = function(element) {
    var car = this;
    
    car.element = element;
    car.element.addEventListener("click", function() {
        car.element.style.border = "3px solid hotpink";
        car.startDrive();
    }, false);


    car.moveCarForward = function() {
        car.element.style.marginLeft = car.element.offsetLeft + 10 + "px";
    }

    car.startDrive = function() {
        car.carDrivingInterval = setInterval(car.moveCarForward, 3000);
    }

    return car;
}

var arrayCarsElements = document.getElementsByClassName("car");
var arrCar = [];

for (var i = 0; i < arrayCarsElements.length; i++) {
    arrCar[i] = new Car(arrayCarsElements[i]);
}
```

```html
<div class="car" id="tesla" style="width: 50px; height: 50px; background: #ccc; margin-bottom: 10px;"></div>
<div class="car" id="fiat" style="width: 50px; height: 50px; background: #ccc; margin-bottom: 10px;"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I think through all my messing around, and late night, I failed to notice that I was using "this" referring to the global space rather than the specific object.  My CSS etc wasn't hardened yet, I was just trying to get the function to loop, I'll correct the rest now. Also, another user commented about prototyping the methods, YES! I will do that, I was just getting the code to MVP and then I'll refine.

Answer (score 0):

You have a handful of things going on here. First, as mentioned in the comments, you need to take control of `this` a little better. Arrow functions (`() => {}`) can help because they bind `this` lexically. You can also `bind()` explicitly. You need to do this when using event listeners and timers because the listener calls the function, which changes what `this` means. The following snippet shows both.

Putting the functions on the `Car` prototype makes it easy to manage `this` too.

Also, I think your css is off a bit, I changed the positioning to `absolute` and used `left` to move the box.

```js
function Car(element) {
  this.element = element;
  this.element.addEventListener("click", () => { // use arrow function or bind()
    this.element.style.border = "3px solid hotpink";
    this.startDrive();
  }, false);
}

Car.prototype.startDrive = function() {
  this.carDrivingInterval = setInterval(this.moveCarForward.bind(this), 1000); // use bind or arrow function
}

Car.prototype.moveCarForward = function() {
  this.element.style.left = this.element.offsetLeft + 10 + "px";
}


var arrayCarsElements = document.getElementsByClassName("car");
var arrCar = [];

for (var i = 0; i < arrayCarsElements.length; i++) {
  arrCar[i] = new Car(arrayCarsElements[i]);
}
```

```html
<div class="car" id="tesla" style="position:absolute; left: 10px; width: 50px; height: 50px; background: #ccc; margin-bottom: 10px;"></div>
<div class="car" id="ford" style="position:absolute; top: 75px; left: 10px; width: 50px; height: 50px; background: #ccc; margin-bottom: 10px;"></div>
```

There's probably still more to do (like what happens when you click a bit twice), but hopefully this will get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct code. function Car(element) - if you print the "element" in console, it will give two divs. When click on one div, you have to send the current div parameter through startDrive(element).

```js
function Car(element) {
  element.addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.style.border = "3px solid hotpink";
    startDrive(element);
  }, false);

  startDrive = function(element) {
    carDrivingInterval = setInterval(function() { moveCarForward(element); }, 3000);
  }

  moveCarForward = function(element) {
    element.style.left = element.offsetLeft + 10 + "px";
  }
}

var arrayCarsElements = document.getElementsByClassName("car");
var arrCar = [];

for (var i = 0; i < arrayCarsElements.length; i++) {
  arrCar[i] = new Car(arrayCarsElements[i]);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>javascript scope with object method</title>
</head>

<body>
<div class="car" id="tesla" style="position:absolute;width: 50px; height: 50px;top:10px; left: 10px; background: #ccc; margin-bottom: 10px;"></div>
<div class="car" id="bmw" style="position:absolute;width: 50px; height: 50px;top:100px; left: 10px; background: #ccc; margin-bottom: 10px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use an object to define your functionality and return that object so that you can have the functionality available from outside `Car` function too (example if you want to stop car from outside). see my following code, it has start/stop functionalities. just run the snippet and see.

```js
function Car(element) {
  var car = {
    element: element,
    running: false,
    start: function() {
      this.carDrivingInterval = setInterval(this.moveCarForward.bind(this), 1000);
      this.running = true;
    },
    stop: function(){
      clearInterval(this.carDrivingInterval);
      this.running = false;
    },
    moveCarForward: function() {
      this.element.style.left = this.element.offsetLeft + 10 + "px";
    }
  };
  
  element.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    if(!car.running){
      this.style.border = "3px solid hotpink";
      car.start();
    }else{
      this.style.border = "3px solid red";
      car.stop();
    }
  });
  
  return car;
}
    
var arrayCarsElements = document.getElementsByClassName("car");
var arrCar = [];

for (var i = 0; i < arrayCarsElements.length; i++) {
  arrCar[i] = new Car(arrayCarsElements[i]);
}
```

```html
<div class="car" id="tesla1" style="position: absolute; width: 50px; height: 50px; background: #ccc; margin-bottom: 10px;">Car 1</div>
<div class="car" id="tesla2" style="position: absolute; width: 50px; height: 50px; background: #eee; margin-bottom: 10px; left: 50px;">Car 2</div>
```

as i am using object to define the functionalities, now i can use `this` with it perfectly.

Comment: dear down voter. please explain why you down voted, so i can improve my answer and knowledge.

Comment: try to run my code snippet, you can see it now starts and stops perfectly on multiple elements.